# What counts as a 'different species' for the Rising Star medals

Tags: pokemon-go

Rising Star is a relatively new Pokemon Go medal that, as per the in-game text, is rewarded for defeating 2/10/50/150 different species of Pokemon in raids.

However, I recently defeated a level 3 Mawile Raid. The recorded number of species I had then increased from 17 to 18. This was despite previously defeating level 2 Mawile raids prior to when the medal was introduced. Following the in-game text, I would not expect an increase from clearing the level 3 Mawile raid.

So what does count as 'different species' of Pokemon for this medal? I suspect that the medal either counts different raid levels of Pokemon as different 'species' or that only raids from a certain date onwards are counted, though it could be something else instead.

Comment: It probably goes back only so far and doesn’t count anything before a given date, just like how the “raid” filter only pulls Pokémon after the filter criteria was update to support it. But agreed, it could be something else

Comment: Just did a Kyurem raid. I had done one previously on 19/7/2020, and it did NOT raise my different species tally. So if it is based on a given date, it's before then.

Comment: Do you know how many you had when the medal was first implemented? I know I got a lot of medal notifications around Nov. 20, most of which I had already received (catch x of type, etc). So there was clearly a re-count of some medals.

Comment: I don’t. Unfortunately I realised that medal existed about a week after it was implemented. EDIT: when I noticed, it was 15 I think

Answer (score 2):

The "Rising Star" medal was added around Dec 2020. Tracking for that medal started some time earlier that year; therefore, if you hit raids before tracking started they wouldn't count yet.

**Counted**:

- Any Pokemon having different number.
- Any costumed/event Pokemon not acquired through raid yet.
- Different forms with the same number in Pokedex: e.g. Genesect, Deoxys, etc.

**Not counted**:

- Shiny version of the already acquired Pokemon.

**Not-confirmed**:

- Shadow versions of the Pokemon.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it for science.

Shadow and non-shadow count as two different unique species for the Rising Star Medal.

Had a Shadow Machamp in 2023 and was at 140. Caught a regular Machamp now in 2024 and counter (pun intended) rose to 141.